# Unique constraint still alows duplicate values

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a table with a unique constraint on event_time and card_nr, nevertheless, I'm still able to insert duplicate values to the table using the statements below.

The screenshot below shows the table I used as well as my DDL & insert queries.
There is also an **EXPLAIN** statement to prove that the columns are unique.

[image]

An error should be thrown since I'm violating my constraint values?

Comment: Please do **not** post code as images. See here for more details why: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551

Comment: I removed the Postgres tag as you are clearly not using that DBMS

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Supported Constraint Types](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/constraints-overview.html#supported-constraint-types)

> Snowflake supports the following constraint types from the ANSI SQL standard:
>
> - UNIQUE
> - PRIMARY KEY
> - FOREIGN KEY
> - NOT NULL
>
> ...
>
> Snowflake supports defining and maintaining constraints, but **does not enforce them, except for NOT NULL constraints, which are always enforced.**

---

> *What is the point of supporting a unique constraint but not enforcing it?*

[Constraints](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/constraints.html#constraints)

> Constraints are provided primarily for data modeling purposes and compatibility with other databases, as well as to support client tools that utilize constraints. For example, Tableau supports using constraints to perform join culling (join elimination), which can improve the performance of generated queries and cube refresh.

Comment: What is the point of supporting a unique constraint but not enforcing it?

Comment: @Djabone Data modelling primarily.

Comment: @Djabone If the uniquness should be validated it could be done by running code for detecting duplicates(for instance when load is complete) or using a framework like dbt(https://docs.getdbt.com/docs/building-a-dbt-project/tests/) or https://greatexpectations.io/

Comment: Two main reasons for including the syntax but not enforcing it
1. Reverse engineering a data model into a modelling tool easily
2. Makes migration from other DBMS easier if they don't need to change their text